# What Joining condition I am missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I need to write a SQL query to return the average rating for all movies and each of these movies is “Romance” but not “Comedy”.

Below are the table list I have-->

```
create table genres (genreid int,
             name text,
             primary key(genreid));

create table ratings(userid int,
           movieid int,
           rating numeric check(rating<=1 OR rating<=5),
           timestamp bigint,
            PRIMARY KEY (userid,movieid),
            FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (userid),
            FOREIGN KEY (movieid) REFERENCES movies (movieid));

create table hasagenre( movieid int,
               genreid int,
               FOREIGN KEY (movieid) REFERENCES movies (movieid),
               FOREIGN KEY (genreid) REFERENCES genres (genreid));
```

I have tried the below  code but getting wrong answer

```
  FROM ratings R,hasagenre H1,hasagenre H2,genres G1,genres G2
   WHERE R.movieid=H1.movieid AND H1.genreid=G1.genreid
   AND     R.movieid=H2.movieid AND H2.genreid=G2.genreid
   AND (G2.name <> 'Comedy' AND G1.name = 'Romance');
```

Expected average: 3.7429411764705882
Actual result:    3.7458333333333333

If I want to get average rating for all movies and each of these movies is “Romance” as well as “Comedy”, then the above code is working fine by replacing <>'Comedy with ='Comedy'

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT()

Comment: Can you have `(Romance, Terrror)` and qualify for the average?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT avg(R.rating)
FROM ratings R
WHERE movieid IN ( SELECT movieid
                   FROM hasagenre H  
                   JOIN genres G 
                     ON H.genreid = G.genreid
                   GROUP BY movieid
                   HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN G.name = 'Comedy' THEN 1 END) = 1
                      AND COUNT( CASE WHEN G.name = 'Romance' THEN 1 END) = 0 )
```